# Portable router with QoS feature?

Tags: router

For testing purposes I need a portable router, i.e. providing the connection from a SIM card, that offers the possibility of reducing the bandwidth at will. I did a bit of research, but can't find detailed information on all the capabilities of this kind of routers.

Do you guys have any portable router with this specific feature?

Comment: Could you please clarify whether the portable router has to double as a modem for the mobile Internet connection as well or not? I.e. is it the router which should include the uplink to mobile Internet or is it permissible to recommend a portable router with QoS feature which could be tethered to such a modem? If there are OpenWRT routers which take a SIM card, those are probably your best bet.